# Running java pipe to mutt

Tags: java, terminal, pipe

I'm trying to run a java command in terminal on OSX and while it works without issue if I just run the command I would also like to email the resulting file but if I add a pipe after my java command and use mutt to send it as an attachment, its not waiting till java finishes before to proceeds onto the next pipe its trying to execute it all at once!

How do I make it wait till java has completed?

Trying to make my question a bit more clear:

What I'm looking for is the ability to run my java command which exports a file to a directory once thats done I want to gzip it and then email it to a distro with mutt. The only part I don't have working is the correct stepping terminal is not waiting until the java command finishes before moving past the pipe. Also my my java script has code that exports out to a file thats easily imported, delimited via ^ to excel.

`java -classpath <pathtojavafiles> | find /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/*.txt -type f -maxdepth 1 -cmin -1 -exec gzip {} \;| find /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output -type f -maxdepth 1 -not -cmin -2 -exec mv {} /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/archive \; | mutt -a /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/*.gz -s "Hourly Report" -- <emailaddress>`

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wait for a command to finish, you should use && or ; to separate the commands. A pipe | is for when you want the text output of one program to serve as the input of the next.

Comment: This might be just what I was looking for trying now: `java -classpath**;** find /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/.txt -type f -maxdepth 1 -cmin -1 -exec gzip {} \;| find /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output -type f -maxdepth 1 -not -cmin -2 -exec mv {} /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/archive \; | mutt -a /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/.gz -s "Hourly Report" -- ` I'll report back the status in a bit.

Comment: well that ceritanly worked so that it called the other commands after java was complete but now I'm getting this error `Done!
Can't stat /Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/*.gz: No such file or directory
/Users/tb582/Desktop/scripts/output/*.gz: unable to attach file.'

Comment: You might have more luck asking on Unix & Linux or Super User